# Use limit before group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query to get the latest 2 messages of the same conversation:

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE conversation_id
IN ( 122806, 122807 )
GROUP BY conversation_id
ORDER BY sent_on DESC
LIMIT 2
```

[image]

Which return `message7` and `message3` as result.
What I need is to get latest 2 messages grouped by conversation_id, therefore the result should be:

```
message3
message1
message4
message5
```

Comment: The best way to easily use GROUP BY with ORDER BY are subqueries.

Comment: @Chevis, Thanks can you please show me how

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get top n records for each group of grouped results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12113699/get-top-n-records-for-each-group-of-grouped-results)

Comment: @Rikesh, I have a table with above 100,000 records, so I can't make similar query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is with a counter in the `where` clause:

```
select m.*
from message m
where 2 >= (select count(*)
            from message m2
            where m2.conversation_id = m.conversation_id and
                  m2.sent_on >= m.sent_on
           );
```

An index on `message(conversation_id, sent_on)` would definitely help this query.  This also assumes that `sent_on` is unique.  Otherwise, you can just use `id`.

A more efficient method is to use variables:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             @rn := if(@conversation_id = conversation_id, @rn + 1, 1) as rn,
             @conversation_id := conversation_id
      from message m cross join
           (select @conversation_id := '', @rn := 0) const
      order by conversation_id, sent_on desc
     ) m
where rn <= 2;
```

Comment: I tried the first method, which crashed my mysql server :'(, let me try the second. (I have more that 200,000 records)

Comment: The second method returned  :Unknown column 'message_id'

Comment: Also the second method was crashed

Comment: When i make some limitation it worked fine: and conversation_id in (122806,122807)

Answer (score 1):

One way to go about this using `GROUP_CONCAT()` and the `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` but it will show you the messages seperated by seperator you specified in the query with conversation id not as individual row foreach message,you can use `ORDER BY` clause in group_concat function also i have `ORDER BY sent_on DESC` so the messages will be grouped and ordered by `sent_on`

```
SELECT conversation_id,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(
GROUP_CONCAT(message ORDER BY sent_on DESC SEPARATOR '||'),
'||',2) two_messages
FROM messages
/*
optional where filter i have provided example for all conversations
 WHERE conversation_id 
IN ( 122806, 122807 ) */
GROUP BY conversation_id
ORDER BY sent_on DESC
```

Also note there is a default 1024 character limit set on `GROUP_CONCAT()` but you can also increase it by following the [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) manual

Comment: Thanks, It worked fine, but as you mentioned it show the message seperated by seperator, so you think that there are no way to achieve it by row?!

Comment: I guess there should be a way to go about getting the messages in each row but i can't have a solution for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Try GROUP BY with ORDER BY something like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(messages)
FROM(
    SELECT *
    FROM messages
    ORDER BY sent_on DESC
    )temp
GROUP BY conversation_id
LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: It will, if you want all the messages try group_concatenating the messages, edited the ans